# Maximal set with orthogonal vectors in a finite vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let k be a feild with 5 elements. Let V be the k-vector space of 5×1 matrices with entries in k. Let S be a subset of V such that $u^{t}v=0$ for all $u$ and $v$ in S:here $u^{t}$ denotes the transpose of u and $u^{t}v$ the usual matrix product. What is the maximum possible cardinality of S?

My thoughts : V is a vector space of dimension 5. Surely, they are asking about the largest subset which has mutually ortogonal vectors. I know the result that a non zero list of ortogonal vectors in an IPS is Linearly Independent.
So my intution says that the maximum cardinality of S should be 6 ( 5 non-zero orthogonal basis vectors and the zero vector).

But strangely, the answer is 25. I think the problem here is that a vector may be ortogonal to itself, for eg $(1,1,1,1,1)^{t}$. Am I correct? 
Please help.

Comment: You've identified the issue. Your notion of 'orthogonality' is coming from the fact that in a field of characteristic $0$, we have $u^tv = \langle u , v \rangle$, which is saying something about orthogonality. But in characteristic $p > 0$, we don't have any such notion, as this bilinear form is degenerate, again, as you note in the question.

Comment: Another thing of note is that if you have a vector with this property, so do it's scalar multiples. And of course, we have $(\lambda v)^t v = \lambda (v^t v) = 0 $ in this case, so the scalar multiples can be thrown in to the set. Are you starting to see why there might be 25?

Comment: I have a vague idea about what you are saying . But I can't see a clear way to arrive at the answer.

Comment: Maybe if you give a condition under which a vector's "dot product" with itself is 0, you'll be able to start counting these vectors.